# Difference between 2b1q and 2b1q with paired disparity

Tags: communication, encoder, encoding, channel-coding

I have a question about 2b1q line code. Is there a modified 2b1q code with paired disparity option available? And if yes, which is the coding rule for a simple 2b1q and modified 2b1q code, plus the voltage levels are something like -1,-3,+3,+1 or I also see a variant with 450mV,150mV?

Comment: I would like to help but I have no idea what 2b1q code is or what it is for. I will take a SWAG: (2B1Q) (two-binary, one-quaternary)  is a line code used in the U interface of the Integrated Services Digital Network (ISDN) Basic Rate Interface (BRI) and the high-bit-rate digital subscriber line (HDSL). 2B1Q code is not DC-balanced.  Is this correct?

Comment: @Gil Yes. Is correct. But I don't understand what will the 4 levels of coded signal.